# Api.Ai falls on textRequest to default fallback intent

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, dialogflow-es, text-recognition, api-ai

I'm using Api.Ai (Node.Js SDK Version 2.0.7 and also upgraded to 4.0.3) and making textRequests to my Agent.

Without any change on my side appearantly half of the intents are not working anymore (the default intent comes instead).

The sentences are proved to work and ApiAi should recognize the correct intent.
In the ApiAi Console these sentences are working!

I could not determine why 50% of my intents are not recognized anymore. Some that are still recognized are a sentence others one word, some have parameters some not ...

My Agent has a lot of intents, maybe it is related to this (51 Intents).

Does someone have similiar issues and maybe found a solution? 
It looks like a problem on Api.Ai Side, does someone know if there is a good place to file a bug on their side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like we got a way to fix the problem.

Someone from Google suggested over here (https://discuss.api.ai/t/intent-mismatch-issue/12042/8), to use the "lang" parameter. I haven't used it before as it is stated nowhere to use it.

I searched the api.ai sources and found out, the parameter "lang" is instead the parameter "language".

When i set it to "de", corresponding to my api.ai bot speaking "German", it does work again...

var apiai = new p.apiai("key", {"language":"de"});

try adding the "language" parameter to the options object, when instantiating the apiai library.

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly the same issue. Many of our 400+ intents are not recognised anymore, when accessed via our node.js app via textRequests. Yesterday everything was working correctly, from 9 hours on it is not anymore.

I have filled a bug report here, as do some others have: https://discuss.api.ai/t/intent-mismatch-issue/12042

This is really a shame, as it renders the api.ai service useless and will force Programmers to take their website or service down until the google team fixes this...